# Problems dynamically adding to form (trying to use onChange and appendTo)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-events

I want my form to extend in different ways depending on the selection of a drop down box.

I have got my JavaScript working so that onchanging my selection it will carry out something. But I am trying to use the `appendTo()` method as I have used before; for adding a single input,  to work for implementing a div and a few inputs. Its not working, hence the post ;)

So I was hoping you could enlighten me as to a better method?

Here is my current code (courtesy of Mark):

```
var selectmenu = document.getElementById("type");
selectmenu.onchange = function() {
var chosenoption = parseInt(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
switch (chosenoption) {
case 1:
    $('<input type="text" value="1"/>').appendTo('#temp');
    break;
case 2:
    $('<input type="text" value="2"/>').appendTo('#temp');
    break;
case 3:
    $('<input type="text" value="3"/>').appendTo('#temp');
    break;
}
};
```

note: updated since answers.

here is constructed in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qzhyp/)

It does nothing currently.

Please help? :D

Comment: can we see the html too please ?

Comment: in your jsffiddle you have mootools selected not jquery I changed that and it works

Comment: can you first narrow down which part is not working? if you put alerts within case statements, do they fire correctly? is the onchange triggered? what value does chosenoption actually have?

Comment: @mcgrailm, is there a better way of doing this? i.e on changing it hides the others?

Comment: rather than append them you could put them in the html but hidden when the page loads then toggle them on selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think value you are trying to case on is a string not a number

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#type').change(function() {
        if( $(this).val() != "nothing" ){
            switch ($(this).val()) {
            case "1":
                $('<input type="text" value="item 1" />').appendTo('#temp'); 
                break;
            case "2":
                $('<input type="text" value="item 2" />').appendTo('#temp');  
                break;
            case "3":
                $('<input type="text" value="item 3" />').appendTo('#temp'); 
                break;
            }
        }else{
            alert($(this).val());
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: ye unfortunately I already tried this with no luck :( thanks tho!

Answer (score 0):

`chosenoption.value` is actually going to be a `string`.

You will need to either call `parseInt(chosenoption.value)` and do a switch on `case 1:  case 2: case:3` *or* change your switch to be `case "1": case "2": case "3":`

```
var selectmenu = document.getElementById("type");
selectmenu.onchange = function() {
    var chosenoption = parseInt(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
    switch (chosenoption) {
    case 1:
        $('<input type="text" value="1"/>').appendTo('#temp');
        break;
    case 2:
        $('<input type="text" value="2"/>').appendTo('#temp');
        break;
    case 3:
        $('<input type="text" value="3"/>').appendTo('#temp');
        break;
    }
};
```

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/7PmS5/) with `parseInt()`**

Comment: hi Mark, first off, thanks, but I have implemented your example into mine, however it is doing nothing still, yet obviously it works on jsfiddle... I am going to update my post to show you my code.